# Is there any possibility of data loss when dual booting Ubuntu 13.04 and Windows 7?

Tags: installation, dual-boot

I am already using Windows 7. I want to install Ubuntu 13.04 along side Windows 7 in a partition that I already made in one of my hard drive but I am worried about losing the data on my drive. Is there any possibility of data loss?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Yes, there is some risk, but to expirience it is better than doing nothing. If you afraid of data lost, the cheapest solution is to buy some DVD-R and burn them with backup. This will help you in much more cases then simply install. And if you will pay enouth attention during install, your data will be safe. Just be sure that you left enough place for Ubuntu on your disks.

Comment: I have already reserved a partition which size is about 90 GB for Ubuntu.Is that enough for a safe installation?

Comment: Wise decision. Yes, it is enough. Just be sure that you install Ubuntu on that partition and do not format others. I guess you are familiar with partitioning so it will be not a hard task for you to deal with Ubuntu partition manager. Simply select space dedicated for Ubuntu as mount point (/).

Comment: Ok... thanks to all who answered my question. I have installed Ubuntu 13.04 successfully. Now i am looking for a proper guide line     to use Ubuntu .

Answer (score 3):

Nobody is going to answer this with "No".

Data loss is most times caused by a stupid mistake and those happen to ALL of us.

But the solution is simple: make a backup. Or even two.

Comment: +1 for *Nobody is going to answer this with "No".*

Comment: I just hope there is no user called nobody that says "yes" :P

Comment: Can You tell me whats are the common mistakes that users make during installation?

Comment: There is probably only 1: formatting the wrong partition.

Comment: So what is the right partition to install? Answer in detail please.  :)

Comment: I can not. It depends on your system lay-out ;) (if you want more info come join the chat ;) )

Comment: ok lets chat ....

Comment: @RedwanulKarim - Partition for Win7 should be at least at 100 GB. - cause after 1st update Win7 is already growing to at least 25 to 40 GB of harddisk. - you dont know what will come next ('flame' with 100 GB ? = Win9 ? - who knows ! )    ;-)

Comment: @dschinn1001   I have made the partition for Ubuntu in D drive and obviously my Win 7 is installed in C drive .Is it right for Ubuntu installation?

Comment: Ok... thanks to all who answered my question. I have **installed Ubuntu 13.04 successfully**. Now i am looking for a **proper guide line** to use Ubuntu .Hope you all will help me.

Comment: Guys... these comments are all very much off-topic to this question. Ask a NEW question if you have a new question by clicking the "Ask Question" button at the top of the page!